# Decoding binary-encoded status string with case statement

Tags: mysql, case

I am trying to decode a 20-bit binary-encoded status value from a batch compute system where each bit corresponds to a particular host condition. The value may have multiple status bits set. For simplicity I'll pretend there are 4 status bits (there are actually 20). For example:

- `0001`: not accepting jobs; all CPUs used
- `0010`: not accepting jobs; all memory used
- `0100`: not accepting jobs; `/tmp` full
- `1000`: not accepting jobs; machine is locked

I am trying to write something like:

```
select host, status, (case statement) exception from hosts
+----------+--------+-------------------+
| host     | status | exception         |
+----------+--------+-------------------+
| machine1 |   0001 | cpu               |
| machine2 |   1011 | locked,memory,cpu |
| machine3 |   1100 | locked,/tmp       |
```

using a case statement. I'm unable to figure out how to construct my `case` statement so that I can concatenate multiple exceptions together.

Comment: Why in the database and not in an application layer?

Comment: What's the data type of the `status` column? BIGINT, VARCHAR, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the type of the column is a `BIGINT` you can use the `&` binary operator to extract bits. For example:

```
select
  host,
  status,
  substr( 
    concat(
      case when status & 1 then ',cpu' else '' end,
      case when status & 2 then ',memory' else '' end,
      case when status & 4 then ',tmp' else '' end,
      case when status & 8 then ',locked' else '' end
    ),
  2) as exceptions
from hosts
```

Result:

```
host      status  exceptions       
--------  ------  -----------------
machine1       1  cpu              
machine2      11  cpu,memory,locked
machine3      12  tmp,locked
```

Example data (running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jix6BfUXKjftDmyyX5oKjy/0)):

```
create table hosts (
  host varchar(10),
  status bigint
);

insert into hosts (host, status) values ('machine1', 1);
insert into hosts (host, status) values ('machine2', 11);
insert into hosts (host, status) values ('machine3', 12);
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. I hadn't considered putting the concat around multiple case statements.